# IntelliSense for HTML templates

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Is there an extension for Visual Studio Code that provides IntelliSense in an Angular HTML template after you've instantiated an associated class with fields and bound it to that HTML template (inline or HTML file)?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Checkout the [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) extension for VS Code.

Comment: It is a quite interesting plugin but I breaks my Typescript intellisence and sometimes crashes..

Comment: It breaks emmet.

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe some things have been fixed by now. It's April 2018.

Comment: This is a fine extension indeed, but this one brings up the issue of the error message on the @Component object when using "require" for getting the template file... It's not that critical issue, but it does show an error in the file, and it can get very confusing while developing, thinking there are real errors in the code, while this is not a real one... bummer.

Answer (score 8):

[Angular Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vismalietuva.vscode-angular-support) 
This one is the best.

Angular Language Service - is so slow in big projects.

Answer (score 6):

I've used a plugin called [angular2-inline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline) by Nate Wallace to work with inline templates.

It supports

- Syntax highlighting of inline html and css.
- Code completion, highlighting, and hover information for inline html

Hopefully that serves the purpose you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I've already moved to WebStorm in this specific app (because of resolve conflicts feature that in VSCode is absent), but I like VSCode because it's lighter and perhaps I will back to this IDE and will try this pluging

Comment: This extensions makes working with inline styles in the component much easier. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a bit late to the party, but I noticed that angular2-inline doesn't show me the typed object when I type the dot in my inline template. Other then that, I like the code coloring so it is still useful to me.

Comment: angular2-inline has been discontinued, try Angular Language Service